# How to convert duplicate keys in a json string to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

We are calling a vendor api, and they return a complex object that contains duplicate keys (I don't know how they are generating this), anyway for simplicity I let's consider this is the string they return

```
{"address":{"city":"Toronto", "line":"ln1","line":"ln2","line":"ln3"}}
```

How we can convert this to

```json
{
  "address": {
     "city":"Toronto"
    "line": ["ln1", "ln2", "ln3"]
  }
}
```

I tried using reviver in JSON.Parse like `JSON.parse(x, (key, value) => { console.log(key); return value }` to start doing manipulation, but even here I only receive `key:line` once

Comment: Step 0: contact the vendor and tell them to fix this. Then: look for a library that might be able to handle this. Last resort: write your own parser.

Comment: @deceze I wish we could ask vendor to do that, then I wouldn't ask here

Answer (score 2):

Technically this is valid JSON but it's highly weird they decided to do this. In the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-4):

> An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on the name-value mappings. When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.

Nodes JSON parser though doesn't consider this valid. But you could use a third party one to achieve it:

```
import * as pkg from '@streamparser/json';


let object = { address: { line: [] } }
const parser = new pkg.JSONParser();
parser.onValue = (value, key) => {
  if (key === "line") {
      object.address.line.push(value);
      return
  }

  if (key === "city") {
    object.address.city = value
    return
  }
};

try {
  parser.write(
    '{"address":{"city":"Toronto", "line":"ln1","line":"ln2","line":"ln3"}}'
  );
 
  console.log("Output: ", object)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err); // handler errors
}
```

Log output:

```
Output:  { address: { line: [ 'ln1', 'ln2', 'ln3' ], city: 'Toronto' } }
```